# Dice problem probability

Tags: probability

*Suppose you repeatedly roll a six-sided dice. What's the probability you'll see a "1" before you see a "6"?*

The Pr of rolling a "1" is the same as the probability of rolling a '6'.
So should the probability be $$1 - [(1-p)^{k-1}p]?$$

Comment: By symmetry, the answer has to be $\frac 12$.

Comment: What is $p$ by the way?

Comment: the probability of rolling a specific number

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's see it this way-

Both $1$ and $6$ are not possible together.

So, Probability of $1$ before $6 +$ Probability of $6$ before $1$ = $1$.

For a fair die, both are equal. So, each is $\frac 12$

Answer (score 1):

The probability to see a $1$ before a $6$ is the sum of probabilities for every possible number of throws i.e.

$$\Pr[1\text{ before a }6]=\sum_{n\ge 0}\left(\frac16\right)\cdot\left(\frac46\right)^n=\frac16\cdot\frac1{1-\frac46}=\frac12$$